# How to fix only first element being sliced in the following code. Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove the "0b" prefix the bin() function adds to indicate binary by slicing for a codingame problem, but only the first element's prefix is removed.

```
st = "abc"
print(" ".join(bin(ord(x)) for x in st)[2::])
```

I expect: `1100001 1100010 1100011`
But get: `1100001 0b1100010 0b1100011`

I'm solving a Codingame problem where you have to transform text into binary without the 0b prefix. I know that this works:

```
' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st)
```

but I don't understand what the format is doing yet, so I'd rather omit it in my code.

Comment: `" ".join(bin(ord(x))[2:] for x in st)`. Currently you're slicing the string after the whole thing has been created, you want to slice the individual elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the ordering of operations.

`" ".join(bin(ord(x)) for x in st)` runs to completion, where each element contains `0b` and then gets joined. `[2::]` comes *after* that and just slices away the two leading characters of the end result.

You want to do the slicing on each string *before* `.join()` concatenates them together.

```
" ".join(bin(ord(x))[2:] for x in st)
```